# Array formula with count.if

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet linked to a google form, and adjacent to the rows of the responses, I have columns with `COUNTIF` to calculate the scores of the items 
(e.g. 
`=(CONTAR.SI(O3:X3,"OK")+CONTAR.SI(AY3:BH3,"OK")+CONTAR.SI(CS3:DB3,"OK"))*20`)

The problem is that when a new response is summited, a new row is added below the last one, thus eliminating the formulas of the adjacent rows. I tried to use `arrayformula`, but it's not working. I read somewhere that array formula can't be used with `countif` function, but that there's a way using query, `mmult` or something like that (sorry but I don't know much about this).

Can anyone help me with this? [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jyYz2Pdhza6naliV-EJO3SX6VqQairH-KD8WDg_tkaE/edit?usp=sharing) is the sheet so you can check it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Can't access the sheet

Comment: Welcome. When you share a copy of your spreadsheet, please share it without the need to request permission. All this is in your best interests; you need to make it as easy as possible for others to look at your question AND your sheet while the have allocated the time. Requesting permission is a deterrent.